# Validating CustomerCreditLimit while generating PackingSlip in AX 2012

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012

I have to modify the scenario, while I am posting the Packing Slip from the Sales Order. It shows me the CustomerCreditLimit. I just need to know in which class and method I should write my code to modify the calling of CustCreditLimit. because In my case if the Sales Order [Payment] type is cash, system shouldn't go to validate the customer credit limit.

https://community.dynamics.com/ax/f/33/p/97761/223636.aspx

Comment: Have you tried *anything* yet?

Answer (score 1):

Put a breakpoint in the form showing the credit limit prompt, run then look further down the stack trace.